# proc report: proportion of group sum

Tags: sas, grouping, proc-report

I have the following proc report

```
proc report data=sashelp.class;
  col
    sex
    age
    weight
  ;
  define sex / group;
  define age / group;
  define weight / analysis sum;
run;
```

[image: sashelp class]

However I do not want to show the sum of weight. Instead I would like to have the proportion of the grouped sum. So first row should be 6.23%. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have found a workaround:

```
proc sql noprint;
CREATE TABLE class AS
SELECT a.*
    ,b.sumweight
FROM sashelp.class a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sex, sum(weight) as sumweight
            FROM sashelp.class
            GROUP BY sex
) b
ON a.sex=b.sex
;
quit;

proc report data=class;
col
    sex
    age
    weight
    sumweight
    perc
;
define sex / group;
define age / group;
define weight / analysis sum;
define sumweight / analysis mean noprint;
define perc / computed format=percent6.2;

compute perc;
    perc = weight.sum/sumweight.mean;
endcomp;
run;
```

But maybe there is a solution without additional proc sql step...